# How to get an array of column names found with a specific text in R?

Tags: r

I write this code to get a list of the column names which contain the following text. What I get is a list of column numbers which contain the following text. How do I get the column names instead?

```
grep("._text", colnames(my_dataset)) # Looking to a list of column names which contain '._text' in them.
```

The sample output that I get is like this:
    [1] 12
    [2] 14
    [3] 19

The kind of output that I am expecting is this:
    [1] "name._text"
    [2] "phone._text"
    [3] "address._text"

Comment: You should escape the `.` if you mean to match it literally, since in regex, an unescaped `.` means "match any character". In R, escape with `\\.`. (So you probably want the pattern to be `\\._text`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called foo, you could do something like this.

```
foo <- data.frame(abc._txt = 1,
              ana.txt = 2,
              bob._txt = 3,
              cathy.csv = 4,
              dan._txt = 5)

grep("._txt", colnames(foo), value = TRUE)

# grep("._txt", colnames(foo), value = TRUE)
#[1] "abc._txt" "bob._txt" "dan._txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
colnames(my_dataset)[grep("._text", colnames(my_dataset))]
```