# grep on elements with '._text' causing elements with '_text' to be selected in R

Tags: r, regex

I wrote a `grep` statement to select items from my list which contain `'._text'`. It works but it also returns items that contain `'_text'`. Is the dot acting as a regex wildcard? How do I escape it? I tried prefixing backslash on it but it didn't work.

```
grep("._text", my_list, value=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[1] "application_text"                      "customers._text"         
[3] "products._text"    "orders._text"
```

I don't want to see `"application_text"` in my output as it doesn't contain `'._text'`

Comment: The `.` is a special character in regex and you should enclose in square brackets. Try `grep("[.]_text", my_list, value=TRUE)`

Comment: when I enter `grep("\\._text", my_list, value=TRUE)` it does work... (I took your output as my_list)

Comment: Did you read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581830/how-to-get-an-array-of-column-names-found-with-a-specific-text-in-r#comment41782317_26581830) on your post of 2 hours ago?

Comment: @jbaums
Yes, I did read. It's a follow up to that question. But that answer didn't cover the escaping of dot there. I thought this is a valid question to be put up separately. Hence, put it up.

Comment: I was referring to my comment below your question

Comment: Sorry. I missed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex, `.` denotes any character. The literal `.` is represented with `\\.`.

```
mylist <- c("application_text", "customers._text", 
            "products._text", "orders._text")

grep("\\._text", mylist, value = TRUE)
# [1] "customers._text" "products._text"  "orders._text"
```

Alternatively, you can use the argument `fixed = TRUE` for a literal interpretation.

```
grep("._text", mylist, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "customers._text" "products._text"  "orders._text"
```